# python 2 "type error: fn() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)" but fn() should have 0 args

Tags: python, python-2.7, function, arguments, typeerror

I'm new to code in general, so this is probably a silly error.  In Python 2, My function runs fine when I run it from the file, but when I import it in another file it throws:

```
File "gofish.py", line 20, in <module>
  deck_creator()
TypeError: deck_creator() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
```

My function *doesn't have any arguments*, or at least I don't think it does but I am a newbie, but python seems to think it does, and I'm inclined to believe Python. I've searched resources for two days now and can't seem to solve it.  **It is not part of a class and that is all the code that is in the file.**

The code I'm using in the new file that throws the above error (all the code in that file):

```
from card_deck_creator import deck_creator

cards = deck_creator()

print cards
```

The code for the function is (this is all the code in the file):

```
"""

Automated card deck creator

"""

def deck_creator():
    # create lists needed
    deck = []
    suit_types = ['H', 'D', 'S', 'C']

    # update the suit
    for s in range(len(suit_types)):
        suit = suit_types[s]

        # loop that adds cards to deck
        for x in range(2,15):
            # if statements for jack, queen, king, ace
            if x == 11:
                deck.append('J' + suit)
            elif x == 12:
                deck.append('Q' + suit)
            elif x == 13:
                deck.append('K' + suit)
            elif x == 14:
                deck.append('A' + suit) 
            else:
                deck.append(str(x) + suit)

    return deck
```

I feel this has something to do with the whole "self" aspect of Python which I haven't fully learned yet.  Any help would be great and hopefully future new users can find this and learn from it.

Thank you!

Comment: Is it part of a class? Is there relevant code that you have excluded? Please edit your question to include an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Well, your guess that it has to do with `self` is a pretty good one. Normally that is indeed related to this apparent disparity in number of arguments. However, it's not clear from the code snippets you've included how `self` would be involved in your case.

Comment: You are not importing what you think you are, you obviously have not saved the file and you are  importing from the prvious versions .pyc

Comment: Are you sure this is the definition of `deck_creator`? You may have redefined it elsewhere, perhaps by naming a class with the same name.

Comment: It isn't in a class, and that is all the code in the file.  As well, this is the first thing I've ever made with that name.  Maybe something in the library that comes with python 2.7 is already named that?

Comment: Maybe just in case run `find . -name "*.pyc"` from your project root dir and if you see a `*.pyc` of card_deck_creator, rerun it with delete to start clean: `find . -name "*.pyc" -delete`

Comment: The find command turned up nothing.  I should be storing my function file that I want to call in C:/python27/Lib, correct?  I ran the find in both my code storage folder and the python27/Lib and it didn't find anything

Comment: Well, not that this necessarily has to do with your error, but: No, `C:\Python27\Lib` is not where your "function file" (or anything you write yourself) should go. Whatever you are calling your "code storage folder" (which I hope is completely outside of `C:\Python27`) is where you should put everything you write, that relates to this project. You are encouraged to have different folders for different projects.

Comment: You have two different code snippets that you've said are "all the code in the file". I would guess the second, longer snippet is a file called `card_deck_creator.py`. But it's just a guess; you should really say explicitly. The first, shorter snippet I have no clue about. It's clearly not `gofish.py` because the error message says `gofish.py` has at least 20 lines, and line 20 is `deck_creator()` on a line by itself. So you see, you are giving us incomplete or incorrect information about your situation.

Comment: I have been saving all my different stuff in code files, I wasn't sure if modules I wanted to call needed to be in the python27/Lib, so thank you for that info!  I put it back into my code file, deleted the gofish.py and made a new one and it works.  Thank you all!